# Is there a way to disable FaceTime's access to the microphone?

Tags: ipad, permission, privacy, facetime, microphone

Is there any way to disable FaceTime's access to my iPad's microphone? I don't just mean mute the mic during a call, but disable access entirely.

FaceTime isn't included in my iPad's list of applications that have requested access to the microphone, but obviously it has access because I use the microphone during calls.

Comment: No. If there was, FaceTime would show up in Settings > Privacy > Microphone. Out of curiosity, why do you want to prevent FaceTime having access to your mic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way I can think of:  Remove FaceTime from the iPad.

But if you use the microphone during calls why would you want to prevent that?

Comment: I was just wondering whether Apple only shows the microphone permissions granted to certain iOS apps, or to all of them. Knowing that the answer is apparently "only certain of them" (marginally) increases my assessed probability that Apple may choose to hide other apps' access to other subdevices.

Comment: Apple trusts its own apps, therefore doesn't request permissions for them. macOS is the same.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Sometimes.  Some Apple apps do have options to list access.